# Python: Passing list object to a function

Tags: python

So, here is my snippet. Here when I pass my original list (temp) to add_more. temp get updated.

```
temp = [1, 2, 3]
def add_more(l):
    l.append(5)
add_more(temp)
print(temp)
```

But here when I do this:

```
temp = [1, 2, 3]
def add_more(l):
    l = []
add_more(temp)
print(temp)
```

but here temp remain same as [1, 2, 3] and is not an empty list why?

Comment: Because the parameter  ```l``` is over written by  ```l =[]``` assignment

Comment: In the first case the list ‘l’ and temp are referring to the same list object where as in the second case, ‘l’ is a new list object that you created inside the function( temp  and ‘l’ are not referring to the same list object).

Comment: @KetZoomer The snippet work perfectly fine. What are you not able to reproduce?

Comment: In the first example you are **changing** the object referenced by `l` and `temp`, in the second example you are **replacing** the object `l` references to. `temp` is not touched.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you manipulate the list you have passed to the function.  but, in the second one you assign an empty list to the label "l", as a result, the list you have passed to the function, does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Because `append` is a mutable operation, and when the code inside the function `l.append(5)` is executed, it mutates the list `l`, in second case, when you are `l=[]` that's creation of an empty list, not the modification of the list passed.

Moreover, you can use `id` to verify it

**First approach**

```py
temp = [1, 2, 3]
def add_more(l):
    print(f'id of l:{id(l)} before')
    l.append(5)
    print(f'id of l:{id(l)} after')
add_more(temp)
print(f'id of temp: {id(temp)}')

id of l:1605604079816 before
id of l:1605604079816 after
id of temp: 1605604079816
```

**Second approach**

```py
temp = [1, 2, 3]
def add_more(l):
    print(f'id of l:{id(l)} before')
    l = []
    print(f'id of l:{id(l)} after')
add_more(temp)
print(f'id of temp: {id(temp)}')

id of l:1605677713736 before
id of l:1605604079816 after
id of temp: 1605677713736
```

In the first approach `id`, that is essentially the memory representation of a variable, is same for `temp` and before and after inside the function.

But in second case, `id` is same for `temp` and before in the function, but not after because you are just creating an empty list and assigning it to `l`, which is just a variable local inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you have passed the reference of `temp` in the function. The `.append` method then adds the new element to it. `append` mutates the list and the reference of the list passed is mutated

In the second example, the parameter `l` is over written by the assignment expression `l  = []`creating a variable `l` local to the function only. So `temp` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

In short, list as a parameter is *mutable*.
In your first snippet, `l` points to what `temp` points to, and thus modification of `l` is also performed for `temp`.

In your second snippet, `l = []` points `l` to this new empty list, while `temp` still points to the original one.

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

`l` is not the list. It is a reference to that list.

If you want to change the value of the list in a function (rather than the value of the parameter that refers to the list), you must use slicing:

```
temp = [1, 2, 3]
def add_more(l):
    l[:] = []
add_more(temp)
print(temp)
#[]
```